# I need to remove white spacing for lines that are separated by white spacing, in a .txt file, from Ubuntu

Tags: linux, awk, sed, txt

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sndaa.png)

Hello!!

As it says in the title, I need to remove the white spacing that separate only by a white spacing to two lines, as you see in the image, the white spacing that have a green line, are the ones I need to remove, but the multiple white spacing that are with a red line, I do not want to remove them, the ones with the green line, are separated by only a white spacing, I do not know if with AWK or SED or CUT will work, the problem is that I do not know how to do it, thank you for your help.

I tried to do it with SED and with AWK as follows, but it did not produce any effect

```
awk -F, '{gsub("\n","",$1); print}' archivo.txt

sed 's/ //g' input.txt > no-spaces.txt
```

Comment: Can you add actual example input text and the expected result to the question (instead of a screenshot)?

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions:

- The input file has "\n" (not "\r\n") line endings.
- Non-empty line contains at least two charactes.
- We don't have to care about an empty line at the beginning or the ending
  of the file.

If `GNU sed` which supports `-z` (slurp) option and `\n` notation is
available. would you please try:

```
sed -Ez "s/([^\n]\n)\n([^\n])/\1\2/g" input.txt > no-spaces.txt
```

Example of `input.txt`:

```
line1
line2 # following blank line should be removed

line3 # following blank lines should be kept



line4
```

Output:

```
line1
line2 # following blank line should be removed
line3 # following blank lines should be kept



line4
```

`Sed` normally processes the input line by line. That is why we cannot process
the input across multiple lines. The `-z` option changes the behavior by
setting the input line separator to the NUL character.

- `([^\n]\n)` matches the last character of non-blank line. `\1` is set as a bac
  kreference.
- `\n` is the blank line in between (to be removed).
- `([^\n])` matches the first character of the following non-blank line. `\2` is
  set as a backreference.

Btw following will work with any POSIX-compliant sed with a help of `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# define newline character for replacement
NL=$'\\\n'

sed -E '
:l
N
$!b l
# first slurp all lines in the pattern space
# and perform the replacements over the lines
s/([^'"$NL"']'"$NL"')'"$NL"'([^'"$NL"'])/\1\2/g
' input.txt > no-spaces.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With any POSIX `awk`:

```
awk '/^[[:space:]]*$/{n++; p=$0; next} {if(n==1) print p; print; n=0}' file
```

If the current line contains only spaces (`/^[[:space:]]*$/`) increment variable `n`, store current line in variable `p`, and move to next line (`next`). Else (the current line contains non-space characters), if `n==1` print the previous empty line stored in variable `p`, then print the current line and reset `n`.

Note: if the last line contains only spaces and is preceded by a line containing non-space characters, it is not printed. If it must be printed try:

```
awk '/^[[:space:]]*$/{n++; p=$0; next} {if(n==1) print p; print; n=0}
  END {if(n==1) print p}' file
```

Note: if you want to remove only empty lines, replace `^[[:space:]]*$/` with `/^$/`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '1N;:a;N;/(\S.*\n)\n(.*\S)/{s//\1\2/;N;ba};P;D' file
```

Open a 3 line window.

If a two non-empty lines sandwich an empty line, remove the empty line and maintain the 3 line window.

Otherwise, print/delete the first line and repeat.

N.B. `1N` ensures the 3 line window is created, the `N` following the substitution ensures this likewise.